# Python - args an **kargs

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

I have this global `function`:

```
def filterBelowThreshold(name, feature, tids, xsongs, **kwargs):
    print (name, 'PLAYLIST')
    for i, x in enumerate(feature):
        if x < value:
            track_name = sp.track(tids[i])['name']
            xsongs.append(track_name)
            print(name, ":", "{} - feature: {}".format(track_name, x))
```

I want to call it inside a `class` `function` passing the following parameters (whose variables are declared locally):

```
filterBelowThreshold('myname', energy, tids, xsongs, value=0.650)
```

inside the `class function`, prior to the function call, I declare the following variables:

`energy = [item 1, item2, item3, ...]`

`tids = []`

`xsongs = []`

what is the proper syntax for the GLOBAL function?

Comment: The code looks correct. I don't really see any problems with it...

Comment: Please show the class you are attempting you write. I cannot understand your current attempt. (As for `kwargs` handling, in case it helps, it works like this : passing `value=0.650` to `filterBelowThreshold` will make `kwargs` be a `dict` with a single key, `value`, whose value is `0.650`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `**kwargs` if you call the function with a explicit parameter `value`, just use normal arguments:

```
def filterBelowThreshold(name, feature, tids, xsongs, value):
    print(name, 'PLAYLIST')
    for tid, x in zip(tids, feature):
        if x < value:
            track_name = sp.track(tid)['name']
            xsongs.append(track_name)
            print("{} : {} - feature: {}".format(name, track_name, x))
```

and call it like

```
filterBelowThreshold('myname', energy, tids, xsongs, value=0.650)
```

or

```
filterBelowThreshold('myname', energy, tids, xsongs, 0.650)
```

Answer (score 0):

**test.py**

```
def filterBelowThreshold(name, feature, tids, xsongs, **kwargs):
    print kwargs['value']

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        energy = ['item 1', 'item2', 'item3' ]
        tids = []
        xsongs = []
        filterBelowThreshold('myname', energy, tids, xsongs, value=0.650)

a = Test()
```

`python test.py` will print `0.65`

You already defined it right, there is no problem. What is the problem you are facing?